# CSV to C# FileHelpers

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, filehelpers

I want to use `FileHelpers` to read an extremely basic `CSV` file into C#.

I have a `Model` that looks like this;

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst()]
public class NavigationButton
{
    public int ID;
    public string Text;
    public string Path;
}
```

The `CSV` file looks like this;

[image]

I want to be able to read the appropriate lines and create a new `NavigationButton` for each record read in from the `CSV` file. I have read them into a `DataTable` using;

```
public DataTable GetNavigationButtonNames()
{
    var filename = @"C:\Desktop\NavigationButtons.csv";
    var engine = new FileHelperEngine(typeof(NavigationButton));
    return engine.ReadFileAsDT(filename);
}
```

but I now cannot loop through the `DataTable` as it doesn't implement `IEnumerable`. I would have created a new `NavigationButton` in a `foreach` loop and added in the appropriate rows, however this cannot be done the way I have started out.

How can I change this method so that I can loop through the object I read into from the `CSV` file and create a new button for each row in the `CSV` file?

Comment: loop through the rows of the table: `DataTable.Rows`....

Comment: @Ric How could I then loop through the buttons and name them appropriately? i.e `Button1.Text = row[0][1].ToString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
List<NavigationButton> buttons = new List<NavigationButton>();
DataTable dt = GetNavigationButtonNames();

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    buttons.Add(new NavigationButton 
    { 
        ID = int.Parse(dr["id"]), 
        Text = dr["Text"].ToString(), 
        Path = dr["Path"].ToString() });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the generic version of `FileHelperEngine<T>` instead, then you can do:

```
var filename = @"C:\Desktop\NavigationButtons.csv";
var engine = new FileHelperEngine<NavigationButton>();
// ReadFile returns an array of NavigationButton
var records = engine.ReadFile(filename);
// then you can do your foreach or just get the button names with LINQ
return records.Select(x => x.Text);
```

The documentation for [ReadFile() is here](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1_ReadFile.htm).

Or there is also [ReadFileAsList()](http://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_FileHelperEngine_1_ReadFileAsList.htm) if you prefer.